# How to create a DataTable and DataView without a Database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable

I'm trying to fill a `DataTable` with data without the use of a Database.
This essentially means I want to mock the database.
Then, I'll make the `DataView` to connect it to the `DataTable` (in-memory) and finally be able to show it on a Form.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is your question though?

Comment: I cant find a way to insert rows and fill them , here's my code atm:

Partial Class DataSet1
    Partial Public Class MusicaDataTable
        Private Sub MusicaDataTable_MusicaRowChanging(sender As Object, e As MusicaRowChangeEvent) Handles Me.MusicaRowChanging
            Rows.Add("Danger Zone", "Kenny Loggins", "Rock", 1000)

        End Sub

    End Class
End Class

Comment: Plenty of examples to be found via Google  - eg https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-vbnet#:~:text=Next%0A%20%20%20%20End%20Sub-,Function%20GetTable()%20As%20DataTable,-%27%20Create%20new%20DataTable

Comment: Is there any way to add them from inside the DataTable class in the DataSet Partial Class? as that what my professor requested

Comment: I have no idea - I only saw your question because it was mis-tagged under VBA and not VB.NEt

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to create a `DataTable` that is part of a typed `DataSet`, create a new row, populate that row, add it to the `DataTable` and then get the existing `DataView` from it:

```vb
Dim table As New TestDataSet.TestDataTable
Dim row = table.NewTestRow()

row.Name = "Hello World"

table.AddTestRow(row)

Dim view = table.DefaultView
```

Note that the names will be different for each `DataSet` and `DataTable` but the principle is exactly the same.

There's generally no need to create a `DataView`. If you bind the `DataTable` to your controls then it is the `DefaultView` that the data comes from anyway. You only need to create a `DataView` explicitly if you need multiple views, e.g. you want to bind the same data to two `DataGridViews` and sort and/or filter each one differently. If you do need to create a `DataView`, you simply pass the `DataTable` to the constructor:

```vb
Dim view As New DataView(table)
```

Note that, if you do want to bind the data, you should always do so via a `BindingSource`. Generally you bind the `DataTable` to the `BindingSource` and bind the `BindingSource` to your controls. You then sort and filter via the `BindingSource`. If you do need multiple views of the same data, then you bind the `DataViews` to the `BindingSources`.